# ngx-bootstrap Daterangepicker open with current and previous month

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

By default ngx-bootstrap  Date range picker shows current and Next month.

I want to set to Current month and previous Month, If the current month is December it should open with November and December.

There is no option found in bsConfig

Answer (score 1):

You can do a workaround to solve it:

in html:

```
 <input
      formControlName="dateRange"
      type="text"
      bsDaterangepicker
      #rangePicker="bsDaterangepicker"
      (onShown)="onDateRangePickerShow()"/>
  </div>
```

in component:

```
export class Component {

@ViewChild('rangePicker') rangePicker;

onDateRangePickerShow() {
  // This is a workaround to show previous month
  const prevMonth = new Date(moment().subtract(1, 'month'));
  this.rangePicker._datepicker.instance.monthSelectHandler({ date: prevMonth });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this feature was now added
use the following property in the config:

```
[bsConfig]="{ showPreviousMonth: true }"
```

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker#daterangepicker-previous-month